# pushState and http_build_query generates random number in query string

Tags: php, html, pushstate

When I use pushState with http_build_query, it generates random number in query string.

For example:

example.com/?**_=1356033912215**&...

However, If I don't use http_build_query, this parameter doesn't show up. Also, each number starts with 13560...

What does this parameter mean?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know exacly what you means here, but looks like you are using jQuery to make requests, that is a timestamp generated by jquery when you pass the '?' char

Comment: Look at the array being passed to `http_build_query`.  Should be present there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong but I believe it is what is referred to as a cache buster. I have seen this before in my own code when you using jQuery's `$.ajax` with the `cache: false` set.

jQuery generates a timestamp on the end of the query string to force the page to reload and pull the data from the server. It's a way to fool browsers into reloading content that has been recently updated on the server side, but may have been cached on the client side.

It appears the http_build_query is performing a similar cache busting function.

In regards to the first few numbers, I venture a guess that the time stamp is most likely generated in seconds, so its not often that the front numbers would roll over if you catch what I'm saying. A million seconds is a long time, so you wouldn't see a difference in the front numbers in a short amount of time.